# how can i extract all the rows of the dataframe where there is a symetrical [column A = i, column B = j ] and [column A = j, column B = i]

Tags: python, pandas, loops, graph

I am working on a graph problem, and want to drop the data where two nodes A and B would be connected twice

A to B

B to A.

Could you help me with that please ?

I have a dataframe data

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| value 1 | value 2 |
| value 1 | value 3 |
| value 2 | value 3 |
| value 2 | value 1 |

I want to extract a dataframe of all the cases where we have these two conditions respected

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| value i | value j |
| value j | value i |

in our example :

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| value 1 | value 2 |
| value 2 | value 1 |

thank you very much !

I tried looping and creating lists but it's time consuming and not very aesthetic :

`l=[]
indexes=[]
for i in data['aretes']:

```
l.append([list(data[data['aretes']==i]['column A'])[0],list(data[data['aretes']==i]['column B'])[0]])
```

index = 0

for j in l:

```
index+=1

h=[j[1],j[0]]

if h in l:

    indexes.append(index)`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the all the rows in the dataframe that are duplicated, I would first create a string representation of the set of your nodes to create a sorted id:

```
df["id"] = df.apply(lambda x: str(set([x['a'],x['b']])),axis=1)
```

Then you can used the duplicated function to drop all the rows that are not duplicated according to the id:

```
df[df.duplicated(["id"],keep=False)]
```

Results:

```
    a           b           id
0   Value 1     Value 2     {'Value 1', 'Value 2'}
1   Value 2     Value 1     {'Value 1', 'Value 2'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your column as `set` then remove duplicates:

```
>>> df[df[['Column A', 'Column B']].agg(set, axis=1).duplicated(keep=False)]
  Column A Column B
0  value 1  value 2
3  value 2  value 1
```

Caveats: if you have 2 instances of (value 1, value 2), they will be extracted. You can also find a solution with `NetworkX`.